# How to make text always stay in center horizontally when changing height of button

Tags: html, css

I recently created a website and after I created a button with a `<a>` on it, the text kept aligning it self to the bottom of the text. 
How do i make the text align to the center horizontally.

I have tried adding this code: "display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;" to the button's CSS, and I have tried changing the position with these code snippets: "relative, fixed, static etc." But none of them changed the horizontal position of the text.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #171717;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: bebasNeue;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <button class="button"><a href="">Buy Now!</a></button>
</center>
```

Comment: The `<center>` element has been deprecated, and obsolete, since HTML 4; please: don't use it, use CSS; further it's also invalid to have an interactive element - such as the `<a>` - within another interactive element, such as a `<button>`.

Comment: Thank you! I know the <center> tag is obsolete but my css skills aren't that good, i didn't know how i would center the button within css. And i guess I have learned that you cant put two interactive elements inside each other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, do not use `<center>` but `text-align` or `display:flex/grid/table` behavior and `margin`. Also a clickable element is not made to hold another clikable element. Use `<button>` or `<a>` . button is a form element and could be tricky to restyle.

example of what you could do :

```css
.button {
  /* what seems to trouble you */
  padding: 15px 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* okay so far, but height is half of font-size !! */
  height: 10px;
  /*Your reset*/
  background-color: #171717;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Now try the layout reset and use flex behavior */
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* ==> because items too big will overflow from the container */
}

a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Test me! (form element) </button>
<a href="" class="button">Test me! (hyperlink)</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! The hyperlink/<a> worked fine but the button persisted on aligning it self to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding style="position:absolute" in the button tag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be – quite apart from the use of obsolete and invalid HTML – that you've defined a height of `10px`, with a `font-size` of `16px` and padding of `15px` (top *and* bottom). That sum doesn't add up, the height would require:

```
16px + 2*(15px) = 46px
```

to contain the text in the centre. To center the text, though I'm replacing the `<a>` with a `<span>` for the purposes of validity, you could simply remove the `height` declaration:

```css
.button {
  background-color: #171717;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

span {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: bebasNeue;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <button class="button"><span>Buy Now!</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As my CSS aren't that good i was basically playing around with changing different things like height padding etc to maybe fix the problem. But i guess none of that helped and just made the code wierd and unusable.

Comment: If you just throw more code at the wall it can be easy to get lost, or to create a mess. Sometimes it'll help to strip out everything but the absolute basics and adjust one thing at a time to see what the effects are. Then start combining where necessary, but when you add things try to use documentation - such as [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) - to try to understand what your code's doing.